# sed vs line with spaces

Tags: bash, sed

have such file to execute

```
exec java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 \
          -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 \
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
          -jar somefile.jar
```

The question how to change IP with using of sed?

Answer (score 1):

for in-place change

```
sed -i 's/127\.0\.0\.1'/new_ip/' file
```

For a copy, you can use

```
sed -i 's/127\.0\.0\.1'/new_ip/' file > new_file
```

Comment: Thanks for idea 
sed -i -e 's/'$currip'\b/'$newip'/g' /tmp/foo

Comment: @AlexF That breaks if there are spaces in either `currip` or `newip`, so you should just double quote the whole command instead.

Comment: Sed isn't really designed to process variables.